# How do I do a mysql join and limit the number of identical results for the leftmost table to 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

My query looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    addr.`Linje-ID` as lineid,
    addr.`Sluttbruker` as companyname,
    addr.`Gate` as street,
    addr.`Husnr` as housenr,
    addr.`Postnr` as zip,
    addr.`Poststed` as location,
    loc.`UX_KOORDINAT` as coord_x,
    loc.`UY_KOORDINAT` as coord_y,
    loc.`ADRESSE_ID` as addr_id

FROM
    addresses addr INNER JOIN
    locationdata loc ON
        loc.`POSTSTED` = addr.`Poststed` AND
        loc.`POST_NR` = addr.`Postnr` AND
        loc.`GATENAVN` = UPPER(addr.`Gate`) AND
        loc.`HUSNUMMER` = addr.`Husnr`
```

The goal is for the query to return EVERY result in "addresses" with matching data from "locationdata" for each one. This query does that, but it also duplicates the result from "addresses" for every additional match it finds in "locationdata".

How can I change my query to return only all the rows in "addresses" (`Linje-ID` is the unique identifier)

Comment: If you have two locationdata values for a given address with different UX_KOORDINAT values, which one should be displayed?

Comment: Thomas: The first one :-) The coordinates are so similar for two locationdata values with the same address that it simply doesn't matter

Comment: That means you could use either of my solutions, although the first one could result in coordinate pairs you do not actually have whereas my second solution would locate the first locationdata row for each address so the results would always be valid pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide what to do about multiple values being returned for a given addresses row by wrapping the columns from the locationdata table in aggregate functions. Here I assumed you simply wanted the minimum value:

```
Select addr.Linje-ID as lineid
    , addr.Sluttbruker As companyName
    , addr.Gate As street
    , addr.Husnr As housenr
    , addr.postnr As zip
    , addr. poststed As location
    , Min( loc.UX_KOORDINAT ) As coord_x
    , Min( loc.UY_KOORDINAT ) As coord_y
    , Min( loc.adresse_id ) As addr_id
From addresses As addr
    Join locationdata As loc
        On loc.poststed = addr.poststed
            And loc.post_nr = addr postnr
            And loc.gatnavn = upper(addr.gate)
            And loc.husnummer = addr.husnr
Group By addr.Linje-ID
    , addr.Sluttbruker
    , addr.Gate
    , addr.Husnr
    , addr.postnr
    , addr. poststed
```

**Addition**

Another solution, which would produce more logical results than above (although no more logical without more information) would be to arbitrarily choose a locationdata row for each address. To do that, we need to know the names of the Primary Key columns. Here I assumed they were called "PrimaryKeyColumn"

```
Select addr.Linje-ID as lineid
    , addr.Sluttbruker As companyName
    , addr.Gate As street
    , addr.Husnr As housenr
    , addr.postnr As zip
    , addr. poststed As location
    , loc.UX_KOORDINAT As coord_x
    , loc.UY_KOORDINAT As coord_y
    , loc.adresse_id As addr_id
From addresses As A
    Join    (
            Select addr.PrimaryKeyColumn
                    , Min( loc.PrimaryKeyColumn ) As locid
            From addresses As addr
                Join locationdata As loc
                    On loc.poststed = addr.poststed
                        And loc.post_nr = addr postnr
                        And loc.gatnavn = upper(addr.gate)
                        And loc.husnummer = addr.husnr
            Group By addr.PrimaryKeyColumn
            ) As Z
        On Z.PrimaryKeyColumn = addr.PrimaryKeyColumn
Join locationdata As loc
    On loc.PrimaryKeyColumn = Z.locid
```

Comment: Thomas, this will surely be non-sensical, since for two records (UX, UY) of (1,2) and (2,1), the result is a location somewhere in (1,1)...

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - Which is why I specifically asked the OP both in comments and my answer what they want to do in the case of multiple locationdata entries for the same address.

Comment: While I'm with you that there is no criteria for which one (random? most recent (highest id?)), I think it is clear a coherent record is desired

Comment: @Richard aka cyberwiki - I think we both agree that some coherent schema and specs would answer the question :). For example, I notice in your answer you use adresse_id as a foreign key between the tables yet the OP did not join on that for some reason.

Comment: @Thomas you misread my post. The inner query takes only the key from the location table, which is joined back (expanded) to the entire row in the outside join - this keeps the location record coherent.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - I get that but suppose a given addresses row has multiple rows in locationdata with the same adress_id. The result will be that the addresses data in the outer query is duplicated. What we need is the PK of the locationdata table (which we aren't given) and to pull the min locationdata PK value for each address.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    addr.`Linje-ID` as lineid,
    addr.`Sluttbruker` as companyname,
    addr.`Gate` as street,
    addr.`Husnr` as housenr,
    addr.`Postnr` as zip,
    addr.`Poststed` as location,
    loc.`UX_KOORDINAT` as coord_x,
    loc.`UY_KOORDINAT` as coord_y,
    loc.`ADRESSE_ID` as addr_id

FROM
    addresses addr INNER JOIN
    locationdata loc ON
        loc.`POSTSTED` = addr.`Poststed` AND
        loc.`POST_NR` = addr.`Postnr` AND
        loc.`GATENAVN` = UPPER(addr.`Gate`) AND
        loc.`HUSNUMMER` = addr.`Husnr`
GROUP BY addr.`Linje-ID`
```

Comment: There are edge cases where this will return UX_KOORDINAT from one record and UY_KOORDINAT from another.

Comment: Could you put that up in a sample, it should not be the case. Anyway it will pick a random record from locationdata, so you might need an order by on that table.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI-SQL compliant

```
SELECT
    addr.Linje-ID as lineid,
    addr.Sluttbruker as companyname,
    addr.Gate as street,
    addr.Husnr as housenr,
    addr.Postnr as zip,
    addr.Poststed as location,
    loc.UX_KOORDINAT as coord_x,
    loc.UY_KOORDINAT as coord_y,
    loc.ADRESSE_ID as addr_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        addr.Linje-ID as lineid,
        addr.Sluttbruker as companyname,
        addr.Gate as street,
        addr.Husnr as housenr,
        addr.Postnr as zip,
        addr.Poststed as location,
        (SELECT MIN(ADRESSE_ID) ADRESSE_ID
         FROM locationdata loc
         WHERE loc.POSTSTED = addr.Poststed AND
            loc.POST_NR = addr.Postnr AND
            loc.GATENAVN = UPPER(addr.Gate) AND
            loc.HUSNUMMER = addr.Husnr)
    FROM addresses addr
) ADDR
INNER JOIN locationdata loc ON loc.ADRESSE_ID = ADDR.ADRESSE_ID
```